# Optimal carbon dioxide concentration range for the human body

Tags: human-biology, physiology

Previously I had thought the maximum concentration of  CO<sub>2</sub> for human health to be given by the ‘Pettenkofer CO<sub>2</sub> level’ with a maximum of 1000 ppm.

But according to [this](https://www.theguardian.com/environment/2019/jul/08/indoor-carbon-dioxide-levels-could-be-a-health-hazard-scientists-warn) post

> a growing body of research suggests CO<sub>2</sub> levels as low as 1,000 ppm
>   could cause health problems, even if exposure only lasts for a few
>   hours.

Therefore it looks like a lower value than 1000 ppm would be healthier for the human body. Is that so?

What would be the target CO<sub>2</sub> level inside a passive house? Since outside it is in the range 3-400 ppm. So with more ventillation we could get closer to 3-400ppm, which is Nature’s default (which shouldn’t be bad?)

Perhaps 750 ppm would be ideal — is there any research on that, either cognitive or related to blood vessels.

Comment: What suggests that any $\ce{CO_2}$ concentration is beneficial, let alone a concentration between $400\ \mathrm{ppm}$ and $1000\ \mathrm{ppm}$?

Comment: well, outside, in the nature, there is 3-400ppm. 
AND: 
that x>1000 is bad = Pettenkofer advise

Comment: Just cause something's in our natural habitat doesn't make it beneficial for us. We've evolved to tolerate starving and fighting too.

Comment: oh, hokay. Thanks :) good idea. but maybe this is not a well-researched topic, since I cannot find some exact facts, what would be the most healthy for the human-body.

Answer (score -1):

https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7575229/  Little researched is a good comment in this time of hysteria.  It is known that the flora starts to die at 180ppm but finding the level the human body can tolerate is difficult.  I would **GUESS** that 500ppm would be the highest we should generate in order to level out the temperature differentials between the solar minimums and maximums.  We could allow the level to rise at the beginning of minimums like we are currently entering and lower it as we approach maximums.  Again I would guess guess 300ppm would be a satisfactory cooling level of atmospheric CO2.  The plant life would love a higher level and we would love a lower level.  We cannot live without the flora remember.  Both flora and fauna must be accommodated as we control the climate.  Weather cannot be controlled but we can do something about climate.  https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC7575229/